# Get value from element using php simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

Im using PHP simplexml to get a VAST xml file from the web. I need to get the values of some elements.

My code is this:

```
<?php

 $myVAST = simplexml_load_file('http://mysite/ads/www/delivery/fc.php?script=bannerTypeHtml:vastInlineBannerTypeHtml:vastInlineHtml&zones=vimp_ads%3D5&nz=1&source=&r=323&block=1&format=vast&charset=UTF-8','SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

 $result = $myVAST->xpath("//Impression/URL");

 print_r($result);

?>
```

Im getting this:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => primaryAdServer ) [0] => http://mysite/ads/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=7&campaignid=3&zoneid=5&loc=1&cb=2c53ba2469 ) )
```

I need to get only the url value:

http://mysite/ads/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=7&campaignid=3&zoneid=5&loc=1&cb=2c53ba2469

But im not being able to do that. I tried to cast to string but with no success.

Any ideas?

thank you,

fwu

Comment: echo $myVast->foo[0]->bar;

Comment: foo; bar? Where they come from?

Comment: They are just for an example..

Comment: I cant do like that. It is to much hard coded. What I would like would be to get the value from the array above!

Comment: You can **ask** a new question in that regard!

Comment: of course that I dont mind to get the value form a xpath expression, but not a hard coded one. So I guess my question still applies. thank you